# Get http request without a question mark?

Tags: python, json, get, python-requests

There's a RESTful API whose documentation gives a sample query:

```
https://www.sample.com/sample/v1/json/sampleFunc/{"input1":"value1","input2":["value1","value2","value3"]}
```

If i put the above in the browser, it returns a json correctly.
If i put the above directly into (python): `requests.get()`, it returns json correctly.

But, if I do it this way:

```
 requests.get(url, params=payload),
```

where I put the diciontary in the url into payload, it returns an exception from the server where it says

> sampleFunc takes x number of parameters, but only y is sent.

Looking closely, the url formed by the above call is in the format:

```
 https://www.sample.com/sample/v1/json/sampleFunc/?input1=value1&input2=value1&input1=value2.....
```

while the original url is of a different format.

I tried something else:

```
  requests.get(url, params=json.dumps(payload))
```

Now the url looks a lot closer to the original (with encoding), but still has a "?" after `sampleFunc`, and still gives the same error.

What am I missing here? Don't all `get` requests contain a "?". What format is the original url in where it has no ?, and takes a json directly in the url?

Comment: That API looks kind of awful. It doesn't expect a query string; it expects a blob of JSON as part of the path.

Comment: Next time please format the code, request format, etc. While posting. This time I did it for you.

Comment: `params=...` is exactly for setting the *query parameters*. That will necessarily happen after the `?`, because that's what query parameters are. The API expects that as part of the URL though, so `url + json.dumps(payload)` it is.

Comment: Does that mean that API is not a standard GET request, since it doesn't conform to ?field1=value1&field2=value2.... ? What format is that URL in then?

Comment: The API doesn't exactly conform to *typical* patterns, but it's still a perfectly fine REST "GET" API as far as HTTP is concerned. The author can dictate whatever URL format they want. They chose a pretty funky one.